# What was the first gift given by Harry Potter?

Tags: harry-potter

[My answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/172633/64888) to a separate question on Hogwarts gifts states that Harry received gifts from Hagrid, Mrs Weasley, Hermione and Dumbledore on his first Christmas at Hogwarts. Harry isn't recorded as giving anything at all.

Harry is hardly poor. He has piles of wizarding gold hauled up in his Gringotts vaults. He was often quite generous in the later books; for example, on one occasion he gave his entire Triwizard Tournament winnings to the Weasley twins.

Did he ever give anybody anything in the earlier books, however? What was the first gift he gave?

By 'gift' I mean an object bought for somebody else or a possession of Harry's that he valued and gave away.

Comment: The biggest and priceless gift he ever gave anyone was love.

Comment: @Discovery I don't understand love. Next.

Comment: It doesn't *quite* answer the question as asked, but JK Rowling did mention  in an interview that [Harry did buy Ron and Hermione birthday presents](http://www.cesnur.org/2001/potter/march_03.htm), but that she couldn't make it fit into the books.

Comment: Actually the first gift Harry gave is freedom to a snake, right?

Comment: @TaylorOstberg If it was meant for a book but cut then I think it should go in an answer (maybe beside a book-cannon answer).

Comment: @TheDarkLord You're the world's greatest Legilimens and you can't find this out yourself? The best part is you could torture Potter while you're searching his brain (or even before, during and after). What a gift.

Comment: @VarunNair his first gift was freedom to all wizarding world by making the dark lord disappear.

Comment: @FaheemMitha More thinking of how it was stated; that's why I didn't assume, see? Some might interpret it as an affront. Depending on my state I could see the way it was worded that way exactly that. But that would vary. That's where I was coming from but I was also willing to give the benefit of the doubt. In reality I know I'm the odd one of the bunch - and this state of mind fluctuates a lot (I can sort of put together where my mind was when I wrote that) and esp this year! That's all though; I apologise for any confusion [or whatever else].

Comment: How consensual does it have to be? There's a lot of stuff that he "gave" to Dudley.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

## The first thing he ever gives is a Pumpkin Pasty.

It's not *quite* a present, but Harry shares his sweets with Ron when he meets him on the Hogwarts Express.

> “Go on, have a pasty,’ said Harry, who had never had anything to share before or, indeed, anyone to share it with. It was a nice feeling, sitting there with Ron, eating their way through all Harry’s pasties and cakes (the sandwiches lay forgotten).” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone, Chapter 6 (The Journey from Platform Nine and Three-Quarters*</sup></sub>

## Also not quite a gift, but he gives Ginny Lockhart's books.

When Harry got Lockhart's books for free from him, he gives them to Ginny and decides he'll buy his own. I'm not sure whether this would count as a gift, since despite Harry needing them for school, Lockhart giving them to him made him feel awkward and he wasn't happy about the situation. Him giving them to Ginny was not just out of kindness, but also of a desire to be rid of Lockhart's unwanted gift himself.

> “Staggering slightly under their weight, he managed to make his way out of the limelight to the edge of the room, where Ginny was standing next to her new cauldron.
> ‘You have these,’ Harry mumbled to her, tipping the books into the cauldron. ‘I’ll buy my own –” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets, Chapter 4 (At Flourish and Blotts)*</sup></sub>

## Harry buys Ron and Hermione Omnioculars at the World Cup.

Harry buys both of his friends Omnioculars at the Quidditch World Cup, when he sees Ron's disappointment at not being able to afford anything.

> “Wish I hadn’t bought this now,’ said Ron, gesturing at his dancing shamrock hat and gazing longingly at the Omnioculars.
>
> ‘Three pairs,’ said Harry firmly to the wizard.
>
> ‘No – don’t bother,’ said Ron, going red. He was always touchy about the fact that Harry, who had inherited a small fortune from his parents, had much more money than he did.
>
> ‘You won’t be getting anything for Christmas,’ Harry told him, thrusting Omnioculars into his and Hermione’s hands. ‘For about ten years, mind.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 7 (Bagman and Crouch)*</sup></sub>

## Harry actually buys Ron a gift for their fourth-year Christmas.

Harry's first preplanned gift to someone is when he buys a gift specifically for Ron for Christmas during their fourth year.

> “They’re only socks,’ said Ron, who had gone slightly pink around the ears, though looking rather pleased all the same. ‘Wow, Harry –’ he had just opened Harry’s present, a Chudley Cannon hat. ‘Cool!’ He jammed it onto his head, where it clashed horribly with his hair.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 23 (The Yule Ball)*</sup></sub>

Comment: Harry bought Ron and Hermione Omnioculars in their 4th year the QWC (prior to christmas) in lieu of future gifts for the next 10 years

Comment: Does giving Dobby a sock count?

Comment: @kojiro If giving Dobby a sock counts, then probably him giving sweets to Ron or books to Ginny would also count - meaning one of them would be his first gift instead.

Comment: @kojiro He doesn't give Dobby a sock. He gives Lucius Malfoy a sock (along with the empty notebook that Lucius had so carelessly misplaced almost a year earlier). Then Lucius passes the sock on to Dobby.

Comment: @kojiro We could actually say that he gifted freedom to Dobby. The actual sock was technically given to Dobby by Malfoy.

Comment: @Arthur so the point he gifted the sock still stands, only to Lucius Malfoy instead of Dobby.

Comment: @Worse_Username I guess it would.

Comment: @Bellatrix 'Also not quite a gift, but he gives Ginny Lockhart's books.' Yes, you're quite right. Not quite a gift; after all who would consider receiving  books by a fraud to be a gift? And you're a formidable witch so I know you understand this all too well. But..maybe you don't understand gifts? That's possible too I guess. In which case good work! Maybe you have some hope after all. Humour or no I would say actually that it *does count as a gift* esp since 1. the Weasleys are poor; 2) he didn't actually know that Lockhart was a fraud; and 3) He selflessly gave them away with a good heart.

Comment: The latter three quotes don't reference the book names - they should. Personally I like to see chapters too. Specifically, I don't remember the gift of books to Ginny.

Comment: I seem to remember him giving Ron a pair of Quidditch keeper gloves. Confirmed [here](https://www.quora.com/Did-Harry-give-any-presents-to-his-friends-Hermione-and-Ron-on-Christmas-or-their-birthdays) plus more instances. The Triwizard gold to the twins, a broom compass for Ron and an arithmancy/numerology book for Hermione

Comment: @Arthur So then we can say that he gave Lucius a gift, right?

Comment: @Jay Yes, but none of those could possibly count as his *first* gift, there would have to things that counted before.

Answer (score 26):

The first gift that Harry gave was the second greatest gift anyone can bestow, **the gift of freedom.**

> Harry sat up and gasped; the glass front of the boa constrictor’s tank
>   had vanished. The great snake was uncoiling itself rapidly, slithering
>   out on to the floor – people throughout the reptile house screamed and
>   started running for the exits.
>
> As the snake slid swiftly past him, Harry could have sworn a low,
>   hissing voice said, ‘Brazil, here I come … Thanksss, amigo.’

Comment: Sadly, the snake probably didn't get very far.  What do you consider the first greatest gift?

Comment: @Tim - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BTQKp9AK7RM

Comment: Take another look at the final paragraph of my question. I'm interested in objects, not generic concepts.

Comment: Does it really count though if he didn't consciously intend it?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67796/discussion-on-answer-by-valorum-what-was-the-first-gift-given-by-harry-potter). Please use this chatroom for discussion, and the comments section here only for constructive commentary on Valorum's answer.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the other answers here:

1. Triwizard winnings to Fred and George in year 4
2. He gives Ron a broom compass in year 5, and
3. a pair of Quidditch keeper's gloves in year 6.
4. He gives Hermione a book *New Theory of Numerology* in year 5.

[Source](https://www.quora.com/Did-Harry-give-any-presents-to-his-friends-Hermione-and-Ron-on-Christmas-or-their-birthdays)